# 200% of posts with this tag?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-posts, tag-score

I was browsing users on Stack Overflow who had earned the [Peer Pressure badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure), and I randomly visited [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17251744/creature-galley), when I noticed that

- Though only one post was visible, the tag-score summaries reported that one tag had two posts,
- The tag with two posts said that the % of posts with that tag was **200%** ?!?!

[image]

There's some small bug in the calculation of these stats somewhere...

(Here is a [Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20211104211203/https://stackoverflow.com/users/17251744/creature-galley) for when the real situation changes.)

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot for posterity? Right now I'm not sure what you're seeing. The user actually has two posts, one is deleted - in that case, as Glorfindel indicates, it's likely that the deletion was marked but the math won't catch up until the cache refreshes.

Comment: Done @cat - I was actually in the process when you asked :)

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how you got the screenshot up so quickly! :D Their deleted question has both of those tags, so I'm going to say it relates to caching - let's check back in a few hours and see if things clear up.

Comment: If it's _just_ cached and not updating, I'd think the percentages should be realistic, i.e. 100% for the `python` and `numpy` tags and 50% for the others, rather than 200% and 100%...

Comment: We have many, many caches. :D So the tag engine is separate from other bits - in particular - so if the tag engine thinks they have two questions with numpy and python and one question each with the other tags... but the system provides the number of total questions asked as just 1 - you get the percentages you see. :)

Comment: Weird...so does that mean it can't (or won't) be fixed?

Comment: Probably "can't" is the right answer here - I'm not a dev so I can only think of one "solution" and that's to somehow figure out how many questions someone's asked by *using* the tag engine directly, and then doing the math from there - but that's unlikely to be very... efficient. Just counting the total number of questions is far simpler but does have the issue of not being synced.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. I didn't mean "won't" to sound accusatory exactly :)

Comment: To the close voters: the issue is likely reproducible on _other_ users who delete posts.  This question should not be closed as no-longer-reproducible.  Perhaps it should receive a status-declined tag due to impracticality, but we shouldn't close it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>Did a bit of digging</strike> Got Adam to do a bit of digging and found that I was both correct and incorrect!

This is a caching issue but it's not related to the tag engine specifically. So... here we go:

1. Post counts aren't cached at all - this means that they will always be current.
2. Tag stats per user are only updated once per day - this means that any time someone deletes a post, the percentage will be off until the reset.
3. Cached number divided by an uncached number = Awesome high percentages!

And... that's it.

This happens in all cases where there's a change for the day - so, here's an example that's the opposite:

[image: Screenshot of a user's profile showing three questions in C# tag but the tag count shows only two questions in that tag, giving a percentage of 67% in C# where it should be 100%]

Above is a user profile I found where the user has asked three questions - all in the C# tag. The user's tag stats thinks that they have only asked two questions in the C# tag and divides that by the total number of questions asked (uncached) leaving the result of 67% instead of the correct number, 100%.

While there may be creative solutions for the case described in the question (e.g. capping the percentage at 100% to avoid it *looking* off), the only way to address both cases is to refresh the tag stats for each user more than once per day. I've discussed this with Adam and we agree that, while this can be confusing - it's only temporary and we think that having it be off or slightly confusing for up to 24 hours is probably not something we want to invest in fixing.

So, we're going to blame caching on this and say that it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) since we don't want to update these stats multiple times per day.

Thanks to Adam for helping out with finding out what's going on here!

Comment: Now wrap the rep in a nice package and give over to Adam. ;)